# Android: TextView not appearing below ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, textview

I checked out a similar question to this but it didn't solve my problem.

From top to bottom, I'm try to display:

- a TextView (header)
- a ListView with an index strip to the right of it (I use horizontal LinearLayout for this pair)
- a TextView (footer)

Everything appears except my footer TextView.

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with my XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:background="#00F"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"    
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:background="#0F0"
        android:textColor="#F00"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use relative layout as parent layout and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to footer textview.

Comment: Why can't you use android:overScrollHeader and android:overScrollFooter of listview instead of separate textviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="0dp"` and add `android:layout_weight = "1"` for the middle `LinearLayout`

Change this..

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"    
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
```

to

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"    
      android:layout_weight = "1"
      android:layout_height="0dp" >
```

**LinearLayout**

1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html

2) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

**RelativeLayout**

1) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

2) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html

Comment: Thanks heaps. I wish I could understand the layout height and weight behaviours better. Could you please recommend a good reference for this that explains it all clearly with exaples - book or link?

Comment: ..preferably with pictures.

Comment: @SparkyNZ See the second links from both.

Answer (score 2):

Better you try RelativeLayout. Check this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#00F"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvFooter"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeader"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#0F0"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="#F00"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this attribute to your 2nd `Linear layout`.

> android:layout_weight = "1"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:background="#00F"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"    
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_weight = "1"     <!-- here -->
      >
    .......
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:background="#00F"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvFooter"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:background="#0F0"
         android:text="TextView"
         android:textColor="#F00"
         android:textStyle="bold" />
        <LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeader"
      android:layout_above="@+id/tvFooter"
      android:orientation="horizontal"    
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sideIndex"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout, it will be easier to show or reposition other items.